# How to check if all related records meet a specified requirement in a MYSQL trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables; `bookings` and `tasks`. Each booking has 1-to-many tasks.

`bookings` table:

```
+--------------+----------------+------+-----+----------------+
| Field        | Type           | Null | Key | Extra          |
+--------------+----------------+------+-----+----------------+
| bookingsID   | int(8)         | NO   | PRI | auto_increment |
| clientID     | int(8)         | NO   | FK  |                |
| vehicleID    | int(8)         | NO   | FK  |                |
| date         | date           | NO   |     |                |
| complete     | tinyint(1)     | NO   |     |                |
+--------------+----------------+------+-----+----------------+
```

`tasks` table:

```
+--------------+----------------+------+-----+----------------+
| Field        | Type           | Null | Key | Extra          |
+--------------+----------------+------+-----+----------------+
| taskID       | int(8)         | NO   | PRI | auto_increment |
| bookingID    | int(8)         | NO   | FK  |                |
| description  | text           | NO   |     |                |
| price        | decimal(10, 2) | NO   |     |                |
| complete     | tinyint(1)     | NO   |     |                |
+--------------+----------------+------+-----+----------------+
```

I would like to create a trigger so that when the `complete` field for each task is set to **TRUE**, the `complete` field of the related booking is also set to **TRUE**. I'm not sure how to check all `tasks`.`complete` fields for a specific `bookingID`.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure how to check all tasks.complete fields for a specific bookingID.

For this part, how about checking that the count of rows where complete = False is 0:

```
SELECT 0 = COUNT(*) FROM tasks WHERE complete = False AND bookingID = <your_booking_id>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample with an AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER.

You will also need a AFTER INSERT TRIGGER with the same code

```
CREATE TABLE bookings (
   bookingsID   int(8)   PRIMARY KEY  auto_increment ,
 clientID      int(8) ,
 vehicleID     int(8),
 `date`          date,
 complete      tinyint(1)  )

;
```

```
INSERT INTO bookings VALUES(1,1,1,NOW(), 0)
```

```
CREATE TABLE tasks
(taskID  int(8)   PRIMARY KEY  auto_increment,
 bookingID     int(8),
 description   text,
 price         decimal(10, 2) ,
 complete      tinyint(1) )
```

```
INSERT INTO tasks VALUES(NULL, 1,'test',1.0,0),(NULL, 1,'test2',1.0,0)
```

> ```
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER UPDATE
ON tasks FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
   IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tasks WHERE bookingID = NEW.bookingID AND complete = 0) THEN
        UPDATE bookings SET complete = 1 WHERE bookingsID = NEW.bookingID;
  END IF;
END
```

```
UPDATE tasks SET complete = 1 WHERE taskID = 1
```

> ```
> Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM bookings
```

| bookingsID | clientID | vehicleID | date | complete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2023-03-27 | 0 |

```
UPDATE tasks SET complete = 1 WHERE taskID = 2
```

> ```
> Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM bookings
```

| bookingsID | clientID | vehicleID | date | complete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2023-03-27 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nFJcFwPs)